# Checking the form field values before submitting that page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I have written following function which checks whether start_date field is not empty and displays proper message when submit button is clicked. But then it takes the control to the previous page. So user has to write again all other fields on that form.
Is there any way to stay on that page even after prompting the error message, with all other fields value.

```
//JavaScript
function checkform() {
    if(document.frmMr.start_date.value == "") {
        alert("please enter start_date");
        return false;
    } else {
        document.frmMr.submit();
    }
}

// HTML
<html>
    <form name=frmMr action="page1.jsp">
        Enter Start date:
        <input type="text" size="15" name="start_date" id="start_date">
        <input type="submit" name="continue" value="submit" onClick="checkform();">
    </form>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put your code in <code> tags?

Comment: Ohh.. sorry I was not knowing about the code tag but next time onwards i ll add into the code tag.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While you have a return value in checkform, it isn't being used anywhere - try using `onclick="return checkform()"` instead.

You may want to considering replacing this method with `onsubmit="return checkform()"` in the form tag instead, though both will work for clicking the button.

Comment: (Also, the form will submit if you return true - so you can just return true in the else condition.)

Comment: @reva Then you should accept one of the answers. I also agree with smerriman, you should hook to onsubmit, not onclick. Also, check again on the server that "start_date" is not empty - javascript validation is a convenience for the end user, and can easily be bypassed by anyone attempting to hack your site, so you can't depend on it.

Answer (score 11):

You can simply make the start_date required using

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" required />
```

You don't even need the checkform() then.

Thanks

Comment: this is the RIGHT answer!

Answer (score 1):

use return before calling the function, while you click the submit button, two events(form posting as you used submit button and function call for onclick) will happen, to prevent form posting you have to return false, you have did it, also you have to specify the return i.e, to expect a value from the function,

this is a code:

```
input type="submit" name="continue" value="submit" onClick="**return** checkform();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know for sure, but it sounds like it is still submitting. I quick solution would be to change your (guessing at your code here):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="checkform()">
```

to a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkform()">
```

That way your form still gets submitted (from the else part of your checkform()) and it shouldn't be reloading the page.

There are other, perhaps better, ways of handling it but this works in the mean time.

Comment: Actually over here i have given a little bit code but in the original one it doesn't get submitted the control goes to the previous page. When all the fields are filled then only gets submitted.

And by changing "submit" to "button" is not working.