# How can I get dropdown Value in MVC created dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I have created the logic which added multiple dropdown on button click. below is my view code

```
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox()" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="DropdownContainer">
            <!--Textboxes will be added here -->
        </div>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
            var div = $("<div />");
            var textBox = '<div class="col-xs-2"><select  name="From" class="form-control">';
            textBox = textBox + '<option value="">From</option>';
            textBox = textBox + '<option value="1 AM">1 AM</option>';
            textBox = textBox + '<option value="1.30 AM">1.30 AM</option>';
            textBox = textBox + '<option value="2 AM">2 AM</option>';
            textBox = textBox + '<option value="2.30 AM">2.30 AM</option>';

            textBox = textBox + '</select></div>';

            textBox = textBox + '<div class="col-xs-2"><select  name="To" class="form-control">';
            textBox = textBox + '<option value="">To</option>';
            textBox = textBox + '<option value="1 AM">1 AM</option>';
            textBox = textBox + '<option value="1.30 AM">1.30 AM</option>';
            textBox = textBox + '<option value="2 AM">2 AM</option>';
            textBox = textBox + '<option value="2.30 AM">2.30 AM</option>';                
            textBox = textBox + '</select>  </div>';

            //textBox.val(value);
            div.append(textBox);

            var button = $("<input />").attr("type", "button").attr("value", "Remove");
            button.attr("onclick", "RemoveTextBox(this)");
            div.append(button);

            return div;
        }
        function AddTextBox() {
            var div = GetDynamicTextBox("");
            $("#DropdownContainer").append(div);
        }

        function RemoveTextBox(button) {
            $(button).parent().remove();
        }

        $(function () {
            var values = eval('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Values)');
            if (values != null) {
                $("#DropdownContainer").html("");
                $(values).each(function () {
                    $("#DropdownContainer").append(GetDynamicTextBox(this));
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                alert("@ViewBag.Message")
            });
        </script>
    }
</body>
```

My controller side gets call is as

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string[] DynamicTextBox)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ViewBag.Values = serializer.Serialize(DynamicTextBox);

            string message = "";
            foreach (string textboxValue in DynamicTextBox)
            {
                message += textboxValue + "\\n";
            }
            ViewBag.Message = message;

            return View();
        }
```

But When I click submit I am not able to get my both dropdown value which are selected.

Please Review below image 
[image]

I need to Get value for all multiple drop down value selected and also how can I put the **Validation of drop down id nothing is selected**.

ON submit click I need to save the selected Value of dropdown in Database.

**Validation code is**

```
 function validate() {
            var values = [];
            $('#DropdownContainer option').each(function () {
                var e = $(this);
                console.log(e);               
                return false;
            });
            return false;
     }
```

**How can I get selected value?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about the creation of these dropdown boxs. You have an incorrect model binding in your controller. These multiple dropdown boxs with name are From, and To. For instance, your action should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string[] from, string[] to)
{
   // your code            
}
```

**Update:** Added the validation code in client side

```
    function validateByInputName(name) {
        var isValidate = true;
        $("select[name='" + name+"']").each(function (index, item) {
            var selectedValue = $(item).val();
            if (selectedValue == "") {
                isValidate = false;
                return;
            }
        });

        return isValidate;
    }

    function validate() {
        return validateByInputName('From') && validateByInputName('To');
    }
```

I think you can get the ideas now.

Comment: Is there a way to validate the multiple dropdown in case there is no select

Comment: I updated the code. You can get multiple value with that.

Comment: No I get that already, i was asking for validations for multiple drop downs

Comment: What do you mean for validation? If there are no selected, they will be empty string

Comment: No I want to restrict the empty string from client side

Comment: You can simply add required attribute to your input like this: <select  name="From" class="form-control" required>

Comment: I am trying to validate with javascript and need to show text, Can You help me out . Please see the updated question

Comment: Check out this one, it may helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279628/checking-the-form-field-values-before-submitting-that-page

Comment: This link is working for single drop down. i have multiples and they are generated dynamically

Comment: I updated the validation code in client. I think it can resolve your problems now :)

Comment: Hi just need one more help, can I also add @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClassId, Model.Availableclass, new { @class = "form-control" }) for dynamic generate as i am doing for From and To?